# How to create a report on the Number of Sales Orders created Vs Bill-To in a particular duration

Tags: reporting

Could anyone please help me understanding on how to create a report in Salesforce on list of Sales Orders created under different accounts in a particular duration

Comment: Welcome to SFSE! Please take a moment to read [ask], and use an [edit] to expand your question. Right now, there's probably not enough information here for anyone to help you. (For example: What is "Bill-To"? Is Sales Order a direct child of Account? How are you trying to group and summarize your report? What have you tried so far?)

Comment: Is the Sales Order a custom object or are you referring to the standard Order object?

Answer (score 0):

For this report, the object type is **Orders** (Unless there's some custom **Sales Order** object that you're referring to instead).

So we can create a new report using the standard **Orders** report type when prompted. From there, you can group rows by the *Account Name* field(**1**) and filter (**2**) on *Created Date* field or some other date field.

[image]